# Gridview Item not inflated?

Tags: android, gridview, android-arrayadapter

create a new `ImageView` for each item referenced by the Adapter

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }
```

This is from [developer.google.com](http://developer.google.com)
It is not inflating the view if it is null. But to add a custom item in the gridview we are inflating the view...

Comment: where is get tag and set tag ??

Comment: what is the need of get and set tag..please correct me if i am wrong..but the code is working properly as its given in the site..but i am not seeing any inflation here..

Comment: @ashwin what is the length of `mThumbIds `? can you please post your code

Comment: post your adapter plz...

Comment: the code is directly from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: @user1140237 mThumbIds is an array of drawable ids of length 11

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter
 {
     private Context context;
     private LayoutInflater layoutInflator;

     private Integer[] mThumbnails 
 =                                                                                                           {R.drawable.kunfu1,R.drawable.kunfu2,R.drawable.kunfu3,R.drawable.kunfu4};

     public GridAdapter(Context c){
      context = c;
      layoutInflator = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     }


     public View getView(int position, View grid, ViewGroup parent){

         ImageView imageView;
         if(grid == null) {
             grid = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.mdv_grid_item, null);
             imageView =  (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_item);

             grid.setTag(imageView);

          }else{
             imageView = (ImageView)grid.getTag();
          }


          imageView.setImageResource(mThumbnails[position]);
          imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

         return grid;

      }

      }
```

Comment: But the view is not being inflated when the layout contains only imageviews..But when it contains both text and images it is inflated to get the new views if it is null...what is the difference between them??